# Redis module RESTORE command call

Tags: c, redis, segmentation-fault

I want to restore a serialized key from a file to the redis memory in a module.

Here is the code :

```
int Unarchive_RedisCommand(RedisModuleCtx *ctx, RedisModuleString **argv, int argc) {

    if (argc != 2) {
        RedisModule_WrongArity(ctx);
    } else {

        RedisModuleString *keyName = argv[1];
        long long unarchiedKeys = 0;
        const char *filename = RedisModule_StringPtrLen(keyName, NULL);
        FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");

        if (f != NULL && access(filename, F_OK) != -1) {

            struct stat info;

            if (stat(filename, &info) != 0) {

                RedisModule_ReplyWithError(ctx, "Error during file read");
            }

            size_t valueSize = info.st_size * sizeof(char);
            char *keyValue = RedisModule_Alloc(valueSize);
            fread(&keyValue, (size_t) info.st_size, 1, f);
            fclose(f);
            RedisModule_ReplyWithCallReply(ctx, RedisModule_Call(ctx, "RESTORE", "slbc", keyName, 0, keyValue, "REPLACE"));

            remove(filename);
            unarchiedKeys++;
        }

        RedisModule_ReplyWithLongLong(ctx, unarchiedKeys);
    }
    return REDISMODULE_OK;
}
```

When i run this command, i get `SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)` while executing line `RedisModule_ReplyWithCallReply(ctx, RedisModule_Call(ctx, "RESTORE", "slcc", keyName, 0, keyValue, "REPLACE"));`

Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Segfaults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)* are often caused by de-referencing a null pointer, which in turn usually points to an address that's not part of the process's address space.  It's a good bet that something of this sort is your problem.  Generally, it appears you've done a pretty good job of verifying variables before using them, with a few notable exceptions:

- The first time `ctx` is used (unless `argc` count is wrong, or `stat`
  != 0) is in the call to `RedisModule_ReplyWithCallReply`. It should
  be checked that it is not null before using.
- The return value of `RedisModule_Call` cannot be checked when it is
  called as an argument to another function.  And according to this *[API documentation](https://redis.io/topics/modules-api-ref)*, this function returns NULL for a wrong reply type.

Suggest removing the embedded call to `RedisModule_Call` so you can test it's return value before passing it as an argument to `RedisModule_ReplyWithCallReply()`.

```
RedisModuleCallReply *reply = RedisModule_Call(ctx, "RESTORE", "slbc", keyName, 0, keyValue, valueSize, "REPLACE");
if(!reply)
{
   // handle error;
}
else
{
    RedisModule_ReplyWithCallReply(ctx, reply);
}
```

***Edit:***
One other thought, the line:

```
    fread(&keyValue, (size_t) info.st_size, 1, f);
          ^//not needed
```

Should be:

```
    fread(keyValue, (size_t) info.st_size, 1, f);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the error occur inside `RedisModule_Call` function. It seems that the variable `keyValue` that is filled with binary content from a binary file can't be parse by redis. What do you think about that ?

Comment: This is the scenario I suggested was potentially the culprit.  That is why I said to call `RedisModule_Call` before passing it as a function.  Curious, did you determine that `RedisModule_Call`  returns null?  My only other thought is to verify that the values for all of the variables passed as arguments to that function are valid.  i.e. is the content of the file `filename` in the right format before being read?  Is the value of...

Comment: ...keyValue (extracted by char *keyValue = RedisModule_Alloc(valueSize);) valid? Also, keyValue is already a pointer, but you are passing &keyValue in the fread function. Try calling it without the &. That is all I can think of at this point. (See edit in my post.)